# Add extra fields on devise user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to create new user with custom fields.
I have created a migration and successfully added new fields to the database table.

```
add_column :users, :status, :string
```

On my view

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="status">Status:</label>
  <%= f.collection_select :status, {'1' => :Live, '2' => :Restricted }, :first, :last, {prompt: "Status"}, {class: "form-control"}%>
 </div>
```

On my controller

```
def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:email, :status)
```

end

And when I am trying to save a new user I am getting the following error message.

```
:status=>["is not included in the list"]
```

Comment: Is there any validation for :status?

Comment: Please provide your class `User`. I think you have a validation on `status` column.

Comment: I think you have a validation that `status` is included in `[1,2]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the permitted parameters for the `sign_up`, `sign_in` and `account_update` Devise actions in your `application_controller`. Something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :status
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :status
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :status
  end
end
```

[See this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) for reference and more information on this.

Also, you need to comply with the validation that you may have for the `status` field of your `User` model.